# How can I show a success messsage with erasing the entered data from the form?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am a new ASP.NET developer and I have the following simple Data Entry Form that will be used for inserting the required informaiton to the database. My question is after clicking the insert button, I want to keep the user in the same page with getting a message about the status of insertion and with removing the data from the data entry fields. So how to do that?

For example, I have the following form and what I want is when the user clicks on Submit button and after inserting the data into database, I want to show him a Success message without keeping the data he entered in the fields. They should be removed and ready for another data insertion.

**So how to do that?**

ASP.NET code:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
        <h3>Adding a New Item</h3>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name: </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Description: </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDesc" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Start Date: </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtStartDate"></asp:CalendarExtender>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>End Date: </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEndDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender2" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtEndDate"></asp:CalendarExtender>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    </asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a code like below:

```
txtName.Text ="";
txtDesc.Text ="";
lblMessage.Text ="Your Success Message";
```

In your page_load event, set lblmessage.Text ="";

Ofcourse, this code should be written in your btnSubmit_Click event.

Answer (score 0):

make your  label message visibility = false

```
<asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Visible="false" Text="A new Record has been inserted"></asp:Label>
```

On the click event of your button you can do the following :

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      // Write the code for inserting a record in the DB :
      // Set the Success Message visibility = true
      lblMessage.Visible = true;
}
```

on page load event, do the following :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   lblMessage.Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in pageload you shold define your lblmessage

```
lblMessage.Text="";
```

after insert your data in db in btnSubmit_click you should show your message and empty your textboxes

```
txtName.Text ="";
txtDesc.Text ="";
lblmessage.text="Your message";
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use JQuery filters to do it rather then doing it on Server side that would be expensive, here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/kR5dZ/2/ e.g.:

```
$(function() {

    var allInputs = $( ":input" );
    allInputs.val("Enter Value...");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          // code for inserting record in database

          // Set the Success Message
          lblMessage.Text = "your message";

          // Clear textboxes
          txtName.Text ="";
          txtDesc.Text ="";
          txtStartDate.Text ="";
          txtStartDate.Text ="";
    }
```